# How to perform USB Host fingerprinting?

Tags: arduino, usb, attiny

I have a Digispark board that is powered by an ATtiny85 microcontroller, the bootloader is micronucleus and it implements the USB protocol in software.

I would like to tell apart hosts the device is being plugged into (ideally uniquely, or close enough).

I have been analyzing the USB traffic with Wireshark but a lot of that confuses me.

So before going deep in understanding the USB protocol from top to bottom, do you think it's possible to do such a thing in the first place?

I'm thinking implementation specific details could be used or if there's USB VID and PID for hosts?

Thanks